# Edit PullToRefresh listview to refresh from bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-view

[Here's](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView) Erik Wallentinsen's `PullToRefresh` ListView on github.

But it refreshes the listview from top only:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to change this, and refresh the listview when it gets pulled from bottom.

Apparently, it is needed to change [this source](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView/blob/master/libraryproject/src/eu/erikw/PullToRefreshListView.java).

Maybe somebody already had this issue and solved it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you use **chrisbanes** 's library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh which supports listview, gridview, scrollview, webview ... Here is an [start guide](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) 
To refresh listview from bottom, just set mode for it. Here is an example that I tried:

```
PullToRefreshListView mPullRefreshListView = 
  (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
mPullRefreshListView.setMode(Mode.BOTH);    // mode refresh for top and bottom
mPullRefreshListView.setShowIndicator(false); //disable indicator
mPullRefreshListView.setPullLabel("Loading");

 mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
          //do something when refresh
});
```

Comment: Actually, this can be view as a solution. I've already changed my listview with chrisbanes's. I'll accept the answer if there will be no answer for Wallentinsen's listview. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/IPullToRefresh.java

Comment: Do you know, however, how to make a distinction with pull down, or pull up to refresh in the Onrefreshlistener ?

Comment: @Tsunaze: In this case you may like `OnRefreshListener2` which supports two methods `onPullDownToRefresh` and `onPullUpToRefresh` instead of `OnRefreshListener`.

Comment: Ha, ok, i didn't test the second listener, i didn't know what it was for, thank you.

Comment: It worked, but is it possible to differentiate the labels (refreshing, loading, release), like one for the up, and one for the down pull ?

Comment: @Tsunaze As I know, this library doesn't support this one. But you can modify the library source code if you want, detail in LoadingLayout.java